# Case insensitive comparison of user input string

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I have a small new assignment and so far this is the code. When it is run, it asks the user to "enter pets that you have owned" if I enter "dog" it is true but when I enter "Dog"  or "DOG" it is false. How do I make it so the case does not matter? Here is the code rn.

```
pet_type  = input('Enter pets that you have owned.')

print('dog' in pet_type)
```

Also, it is due today so fast help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`str.lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) to lowercase the string and then compare the value. For example:

```
'dog' == pet_type.lower()

# 'DOG'.lower() ==> 'dog'
```

Note: To check for an exact match, you need to use `==` instead of `in`. As `in` does a substring match. Hence `'dog' in 'dogogogo'` will also return `True`

Comment: Thx! I am still using it because that is what was taught in the lesson but the other part works. Thank you for ur explanation

Answer (score 0):

#### Your choices:

You can use `<str>.lower()` or `<str>.upper()`.

`lower()` coverts the whole string to lowercase, and `upper()` converts the whole string to uppercase. You can then compare against this value once, rather than tens or even hundreds of comparisons/`if`s.

#### Examples:

`lower()`:

```py
foo = input('foo or bar? ')
if foo.lower() == 'foo': print ('Good choice!')
elif foo.lower() == 'bar': print ('Bad choice...')
else: print ('Only foo or bar.')
```

`upper()`:

```py
foo = input('foo or bar? ')
if foo.upper() == 'FOO': print ('Good choice!')
elif foo.upper() == 'BAR': print ('Bad choice...')
else: print ('Only foo or bar.')
```